# Login Error: There is an error in logging you into this application (error code : 13805173)

Tags: facebook

Our oauth signin was working fine until recently.

The signin throws an error on the Facebook site:

[image]

This error says:

> Login Error: There is an error in logging you into this application. Please try again later.

It's been failing for several days now - how can I resolve this?

Comment: What’s with those parameters – color, icon, integration? None of those are “official” parameters for the FB login dialog. I suggest you start by creating a login dialog URL that contains the necessary parameters as described in the documentation only, and see what that gets you.

Comment: @C I tried it, same issues. Those parameters are just ignored by facebook (it should do). We are just passing an array that is blindly convert into parameters by the oauth library. We could filter it, but after trying it, didn't do much.

Comment: Why so many down votes on this questions? 

Facebook is really not helping with the error message. Has there been any Facebook API change recently?

Comment: I'm facing the same issue. Did you figure out how to solve it?

Comment: Seeing the same problem here as well. Did anyone solve this?

Comment: I'm hitting this on mobile as well using iOS and Android mobile SDKs.  Nothing has changed on our app at all.  I suspect it's something wrong on FB end

Answer (score 0):

The issue only occurs when the user is already logged into facebook.

If the user is not logged in, then Facebook prompt for login and the signin workflow works correctly and the tokens are returned.

Is there a configuration change on FB side that now prevent this from working?

Thanks